# How do I receive a HIGH or LOW signal from an IR sensor on an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm trying to use an IR sensor with my Arduino Uno and only want a HIGH or LOW signal without decoding making any IR signal turn the state to a 1 or 0.   There is also a motion sensor but that code has been removed.

```cpp
int ledPin = 13; // choose the pin for the LED
int inputPin = 2; // choose the input pin (for PIR sensor)
int pirState = LOW; // we start, assuming no motion detected
int val = 0; // variable for reading the pin status
int relayPin = 4; //PIN FOR RELAY OPERATION
int irPin = 7; //IR Sensor pin
int lightState = 0;
int irVal = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT); // declare sensor as input
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(irPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  irVal = digitalRead(irPin);
  if (irVal == HIGH) {
    lightState = 1;
    Serial.println("IR received");
    while(irVal == HIGH) {
      irVal = digitalRead(irPin);
      if(irVal == HIGH) {
        irVal = LOW;
      } else {
        irVal = HIGH;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: What type of IR sensor are you using?  An analog sensor with a 0-5V return values between 0 and 1023 on the Arduino.  If you only want a binary HIGH/LOW using an analog sensor, you'll need a function that thresholds the sensor values and returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to say that the input is not working correctly? Maybe try INPUT_PULLUP instead of INPUT in the setup loop.

For example:
pinMode(inputPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
Information about this principle you can find here: 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/InputPullupSerial